# Why has Marek stopped contributing?

Tags: discussion

Do the moderators have any idea why the user [Marek](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/329/marek) has suddenly stopped contributing to physics stack exchange?

I really miss his brilliant answers and I'm just wondering if Lubos posting about him and Ron in a disrespecful way some time ago on his [blog](http://motls.blogspot.com/2011/08/unity-and-uniqueness-of-string-theory.html) might have had something to do with it?

Answer (score 10):

Because I am busy with quite a lot of stuff. But I might get back when things settle down a bit.

As for the Luboš, I don't mind in the slightest since I have been familiar with his overaggressive (at least on the internet) personality for some time now. But this is totally OT, just saying 'cause you asked ;)

Comment: If you have better things to do, then that's perfectly ok with me ;) I just didn't like the idea of talented people being harrassed off the site, which I now know isn't the case for you. I think I need to toughen up a bit.

Comment: -1 This answer is *obviously* incorrect.

Comment: @wsc I thought you must be joking, but you really did deduct. So what's the "correct" answer then?

Comment: @user2146, up and down votes are not taken so seriously on meta sites. So it was most probably still a joke.

Comment: Also, I didn't actually downvote. If points were reduced, someone else must have done it.

Comment: @wsc: you are *obviously* right :P But really, just because I have few secs a day to view the site it doesn't mean I have enough time to post a valuable answer, unfortunately.

Comment: I, for one, would rather have one @Marek than a dozen Luboš.

Comment: Sorry Marek, but I'd rather have the dozen Lubošes... Unfortunately that's not an option.